# Is jQuery .attr() method XSS safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

Here is my jquery code snippet

```
       var testURL = $(location).attr('search').split('&');
       ....
       $(location).attr('search',testURL.join('&'));
```

Is attr() method XSS safe. Looks like not as i did not find anything related to escape at [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) If not how can i escape it ?

**UPDATE :-**

Basically my question is in context of getting and setting both.First i am getting `$(location).attr('search').split('&');`and doing split on it. 
Can there be any here here if query string contains malicious data?

Also while setting i am doing `$(location).attr('search',testURL.join('&')`, what if `testURL` contains malicious data ?

Comment: Using the `attr` method to set properties is wrong. You should use `prop` instead. But to be honest, using `$(location)` is wrong in the first place. It's not a DOM object, there is literally no reason to ever wrap this in a jQuery object - use `location.search = ...` instead.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(location).attr('search', whatever);
```

is equivalent to

```
location.search = whatever;
```

So it's no more or less safe than the plain Javascript version.

Comment: @Barrmar. I did not get why its safe. what if `$(location).attr('search').` contains the query string which has malicious data

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice that you were assigning to `location`, which performs a redirect.

Comment: What kind of malicious data can there be in the query string? Whether something is malicious depends on what you do with it, the query string doesn't do anything by itself.

Comment: I saw that, it doesn't answer my question. Maybe you could give a specific example.

Comment: answer to your question is malicious script can contain any script tag and can it be executed ? I believe not as we are not rendering on page but just using it for redirection. Right ?

Comment: Right. Unless there's something on the page that copies from the URL to the page content, it won't be rendered. It's just data that the web application can use.

Comment: There are some server exploits that can be triggered with certain query strings, so if you perform a full redirection by assigning to `document.location` it could do that.

Comment: One last question is that i am more concerned with getting part where first i am getting  it  with `$(location).attr('search')` in function. What if
current url contains some script tag. Is there a possibility that script it can be executed ?

Comment: No. Scripts are not executed in the URL. They aren't even executed if you assign to `.innerHTML`. You have to explicitly create a `<script>` element with `document.createElement` and `appendChild`.

Comment: The only way a script could be executed from the URL is if you do something like `document.location = "javascript:alert('foo')"`